# C++ bind UDP Socket Address Family not suppoerted

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, bind

Running a Linux system on a PowerPC Architecture which is connected via Ethernet to another Device obtaining a UDP connection (Package Based), 
I try to setup a socket and bind it to my Port `8813`. But whenever I enter a Port different from `0`, Binding fails.

Here is the code:

```
int connector::initUDPSocket(){
    struct hostent *server;
    //Construct Socket
    struct sockaddr_in {
        __uint8_t sin_len;
        sa_family_t sin_family;
        in_port_t sin_port;
        struct in_addr sin_addr;
        char sin_zero[8];
    }
    ;
    sockaddr_in socketaddress;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); /* length of addresses */


    udpsocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM ,0);

    if(udpsocket<=0)
    {
        printf("No Socket opened!");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ONE Socket opened!");

        memset((char *) &socketaddress,0, sizeof(socketaddress));


        socketaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socketaddress.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(inet_addr("192.168.0.10"));//<=That's the external devices address;// htonl(inet_addr("192.168.0.1"));//<=That's my devices address;//htonl(INADDR_ANY);//INADDR_ANY;//
        socketaddress.sin_port = htons(8813);//8813;//htonl(8813);//htons(0); //<=Only the last one works


        int bind_result=bind(udpsocket,(struct sockaddr *)&socketaddress,sizeof(socketaddress));
        if( bind_result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {

            printf(LFL_CRI,"BIND failed! Error: %s",strerror(errno)); //Returns "BIND failed! Error: Address family not supported by protocol"
        }
        else
        {
            printf(LFL_CRI,"BIND worked!");
                //Nun den Listener für den DatenStream aufsetzen.
                char      SockAddrBuffer[sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage)];
                socklen_t SockAddrBufferSize = sizeof(SockAddrBuffer);
                int numofbytes=recvfrom(udpsocket, udp_buffer, UDP_BUFFERSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)SockAddrBuffer, &SockAddrBufferSize);
                if (numofbytes >0)
                {
                    printf("%i bytes received",numofbytes);
                }
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What I found out so far:

- Ping `192.168.0.10` is possible
- Data seem not to be blocked by the firewall; `iptables -nvL` mentioned no dropped packages. I added a new rule for that, before this rule was applied, the number or dropped packages increased when the external device was connected.
- Using a test tool on my Windows PC (simply debugging, if there's incoming traffic on a port; connecting the external device to it), I receive data; so, the external device definitely sends data
- Binding to Port `0` works; the `netstat -au` mentions a tool listening on port `2`, while the program is running
- Error Message: `BIND failed! Error: Address family not supported by protocol`

So, 2 questions are open here:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What am I understanding wrong about "bind". What sense does it make to listen to "some random port assigned to my program by the system"? I mean, if I setup an http-Server, I want to listen to Port `80` and not to port "RANDOM". What is this good for?

Comment: Why are you redefining `sockaddr_in`? Include `<netinet/in.h>` to get the one that's correct for your tool chain. If it was left out of the tool chain, there is probably a good reason.

Comment: At some places you are using `printf` instead of `fprintf`. `udpsocket` is undeclared, I guess it should be integer. Can you please create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've redefined `struct sockaddr_in` in your code.  If is in any way different from how the system defines it, any code that attempts to use this struct will not work properly.

You need to `#include <netinet/in.h>` to get the proper definition of this struct.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem :)